# Targeting a specific iframe

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, iframe

I am using an Organic Theme "Music" theme and have this added this code to my WordPress site to help make sure that SoundCloud and MixCloud oEmbeds do not stretch the width of the page.

```
iframe,
embed {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The theme uses fitvids, but I tried to change that code based on the forum support and that didn't work, however, adding this iframe code did work to solve the SoundCloud and MixCloud oEmbed size issue, but then it messed with something else.

JetPack from WordPress has a Twitter widget that is impacted by this code. It will not display the full height of the widget at 100% for some reason. It will only display one tweet and not expand out to its full height. But if I change the height of the iframe code to "600px", it will display properly, however, then all oEmbeds will be at 600px.

The iframe code is as follows:

```
<iframe id="twitter-widget-0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" class="twitter-timeline twitter-timeline-rendered" allowfullscreen="" style="border: none; max-width: 100%; min-width: 180px; width: 370px;" title="Twitter Timeline" height="1755"></iframe>
```

Can I target that specific Twitter widget instance / iframe like this:

```
iframe.twitter-widget-0,
embed {
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Or, does that not work?

I'm not a developer, but a project manager and just need some help.

Comment: twitter-widget-0 is ID not Class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`twitter-widget-0` is `ID` not `Class` so Please try this

```
iframe#twitter-widget-0{
/*your code here*/
}
```